# float division by zero error related to ngram and nltk

Tags: python, nltk

My task is to use 10-fold cross validation method with uni, bi and trigrams in a corpus and compare their accuracy. However, I am stuck with a float division error. All of these codes are given by the question setter except for the loop, so the error is probably there. Here, we are only using the first 1000 sentences to test the program, and that line will be removed once I know the program runs.

```
import codecs
mypath = "/Users/myname/Desktop/"
corpusFile = codecs.open(mypath + "estonianSample.txt",mode="r",encoding="latin-1")
sentences = [[tuple(w.split("/")) for w in line[:-1].split()] for line in corpusFile.readlines()]
corpusFile.close()


from math import ceil
N=len(sentences)
chunkSize = int(ceil(N/10.0))


sentences = sentences[:1000]

chunks=[sentences[i:i+chunkSize] for i in range(0, N, chunkSize)]

for i in range(10):

    training = reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,[chunks[j] for j in range(10) if j!=i])
    testing = chunks[i]

from nltk import UnigramTagger,BigramTagger,TrigramTagger
t1 = UnigramTagger(training)
t2 = BigramTagger(training,backoff=t1)
t3 = TrigramTagger(training,backoff=t2)

t3.evaluate(testing)
```

This is what the error says:

```
runfile('/Users/myname/pythonhw3.py', wdir='/Users/myname')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-1-921164840ebd>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/Users/myname/pythonhw3.py', wdir='/Users/myname') 
  File "/Users/myname/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 580, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "/Users/myname/pythonhw3.py", line 34, in <module>
    t3.evaluate(testing)
  File "/Users/myname/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/tag/api.py", line 67, in evaluate
    return accuracy(gold_tokens, test_tokens)
  File "/Users/myname/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nltk/metrics/scores.py", line 40, in accuracy
    return float(sum(x == y for x, y in izip(reference, test))) / len(test)    
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

Comment: Can you post the full output of the error?

Comment: Edited! added the full output!

Answer (score 0):

Your error is occurring due to the return value being close to negative infinity.

The line specifically causing the issue is,

```
t3.evaluate(testing)
```

What you can do instead is,

```
try:
    t3.evaluate(testing)
except ZeroDivisonError:
    # Do whatever you want it to do
    print(0)
```

It works on my end. Try it out!

The answer is four years later, but hopefully, a fellow net citizen can find this helpful.